# Pilha, funcao pop, ela tem que retirar no final

Tags: c, stack

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct pilhaElement{
    int data;
    struct pilhaElement *next;
}PilhaElment;
typedef struct pilha{
    PilhaElment *head;
    PilhaElment *tail;
    int size;
}Pilha;
Pilha *iniciarpilha(){
    Pilha *pi = (Pilha *) malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
    if(pi!=NULL){
        pi->size = 0;
        pi->head = NULL;
        pi->tail = NULL;
    }
    return pi;
}
void liberapilha(Pilha *pi){
    if(pi != NULL){
        PilhaElment *node;
        while(pi->head!=NULL){
            node = pi->head;
            pi->head = pi->head->next;
            free(node);
        }
        free(pi);
    }
}
void push(Pilha *pi,int num){
    if(pi == NULL){
        return;
    }
    PilhaElment *node = (PilhaElment *) malloc(sizeof(PilhaElment));
    if(pi->size == 0){
        node->data = num;
        node->next = NULL;
        pi->head = node;
        pi->tail = node;
    }
    else{
        node->data = num;
        node->next = NULL;
        pi->tail->next = node;
        pi->tail = node;
    }
    (pi->size)++;
}
void printpilha(Pilha *pi){
    if(pi == NULL){
            printf("Pilha vazia.\n");
            return;
    }
    PilhaElment *node = pi->head;
    while(node != NULL){
        printf("%d ",node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
void pop(Pilha *pi){
    if(pi == NULL){
        printf("Pilha vazia.\n");
    }
    PilhaElment *node = pi->head;
   while(node!=pi->tail){
        node = node->next;
   }
  node->next = NULL;
  free();
}
int main(){
    Pilha *pi = iniciarpilha();
    push(pi,1);
    push(pi,2);
    push(pi,3);
    printpilha(pi);
    pop(pi);
    printf("\n%d",pi->tail->data);
   //printpilha(pi);
    return 0;
}
```

Alguém me da ajuda a resolver o problema da função pop, ela deveria estar retirando no final, mas eu estou quebrando a pila quando tento, a inserção da pilha esta sendo no final.

Comment: Tem como [edit] a pergunta e explicar melhor o problema? Se está implementando uma pilha, não faz sentido você remover um elemento do final, visto que ela é LIFO (last in, first out).

Comment: Sim, eu sei que é LIFO, por isso estou inserindo no final. Por isso estou removendo no final.

Comment: De fato, eu devo ter entendido errado. A dica de [edit] a pergunta permanece. Explique o que cada função deveria fazer e o que cada uma está fazendo, assim como a lógica que tentou implementar nas que não estão funcionando.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss , se o @PedroHenriqueFariaTeixeira colocar os elementos novos no final, então faz sentido remover do fim. @PedroHenriqueFariaTeixeira , como você está usando lista ligada, eu iria dar o `push` e o `pop` no cabeçalho (`head` no seu código) da pilha; prefiro fazer essa manipulação da pilha no final dela quando a implemento sobre um vetor

Answer (score 2):

Uma pilha ou uma fila se consegue com comportamento. Basta seguir o contrato respectivo que de alcança o *comportamento de pilha* ou o *comportamento de fila* desejado.

O contrato da **pilha** é LIFO:

> last in, first out

Que traduzindo fica:

> último a entrar, primeiro a sair

Então, precisamos de duas ações para fazer com que a estrutura de dados se comporte como uma pilha:

- uma função que insira elemento (conhecida por `push`);
- uma função que remova elemento (conhecida por `pop`).

Vou colocar aqui duas implementações distintas para isso: a primeira é sobre um vetor de tamanho fixo; a segunda é sobre lista simplesmente encadeada. Com alguns ajustes para gerenciar o vetor interno, é possível generalizar para um vetor de tamanho arbitrário.

### Pilha sobre vetor de tamanho fixo

Uma pilha feita sobre um vetor de tamanho fixo depende do tamanho do vetor criado. Para saber onde colocar no vetor, também é interessante saber quantos elementos já foram preenchidos.

```
typedef struct pilha_vetor_fixo {
    int tamanho, ocupado;
    int *dados;
} Pilha_vetor_fixo;

Pilha_vetor_fixo *init_pilha_vetor_fixo(int tamanho) {
    int *dados = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * tamanho);
    Pilha_vetor_fixo *ret = (Pilha_vetor_fixo*) malloc(sizeof(Pilha_vetor_fixo));

    ret->ocupado = 0;
    ret->tamanho = tamanho;
    ret->dados = dados;

    return ret;
}

/* retorna 1 se deu certo, 0 caso esteja cheio/falhou a inserção */
int push_pilha_vetor_fixo(Pilha_vetor_fixo *p, int dado) {
    /* primeiro, verifica se tem espaço para inserir */
    if (p->ocupado < p->tamanho) {
        /* tem espaço, então insere no fim */
        p->dados[p->ocupado] = dado;
        p->ocupado += 1;
        return 1;
     } else {
         /* não tem espaço suficiente, retornar 0 */
         return 0;
      }
}

/* pop retornando o elemento da pilha sendo removido, ou -1 caso não seja possível */
 int pop_pilha_vetor_fixo(Pilha_vetor_fixo *p) {
     /* só é possível remover se existir pelo menos um elemento */
     if (p->ocupado > 0) {
         /* decrementa quantidade de casas ocupadas e retorna último elemento */
         p->ocupado -= 1;
         return p->dados[p->ocupado];
     } else {
         return -1; /* código de falha do retorno */
     }
}
```

### Pilha sobre lista ligada simples

Aqui temos uma pilha que aponta para a cabeça de uma lista ligada simples. Assim, só preciso me preocupar com o elemento no topo da pilha e, ao acrescentar um novo elemento, fazer ele apontar para o resto da pilha.

```
typedef struct lista {
    int dado;
    struct lista *prox;
} Lista;

typedef struct pilha_lista {
    Lista *topo;
    /* sim, dá para atender ao contrato usando apenas esse elemento */
} Pilha_lista;

/* iniciando uma pilha baseada em lista, não precisa de nenhum parâmetro */
Pilha_lista *init_pilha_lista() {
    Pilha_lista *ret = (Pilha_lista*) malloc(sizeof(Pilha_lista));
     ret->topo = NULL;
     return ret;
}

/* iniciar um elemento da lista tendo seu dado e o próximo */
Lista *init_lista(int dado, Lista *prox) {
    Lista *ret = (Lista*) malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    ret->dado = dado;
    ret->prox = prox;
    return ret;
}

/* a priori, não vou tratar falha de malloc, então vou assumir que sempre dá certo */
int push_pilha_lista(Pilha_lista *p, int dado) {
    /* crio um novo elemento da lista apontando para a lista atual, então atualizo o topo */
    Lista *novo_elemento = init_lista(dado, p->topo);
    p->topo = novo_elemento;

    return 1;
}

/* assumindo o mesmo código de erro que o exemplo de pilha sobre vetor fixo */
int pop_pilha_lista(Pilha *p) {
    /* verificar o topo é o suficiente para garantir que há elementos na pilha */
    if (p->topo != NULL) {
        /* guardar o nó do topo atual, atualizar o topo para o próximo da lista, salvar o dado numa variável, liberar o espaço alocado para o elemento removido */
        Lista *removido = p->topo;
        int dado_removido = removido->dado;
        p->topo = removido->prox;
        free(removido);

        return dado_removido;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```